# Mongodb--How to find records overlapping an interval?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have almost 70 million records in a Mongodb collection with fields (among others) like

```
start: 13653506610,
finish: 13653506650
```

(the values are Unix epoch seconds, if that matters). For each 30 second interval from the start of the collection to the end of the collection I want to find and aggregate the records the overlap the interval, including for how long each overlaps.  The question is how best to do this?

I created an index of the form

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({start: 1, finish: 1})
```

but even with this index a query of the form

```
db.coll.find({start: {$lt: 13653506630}, finish: {$gte: 13653506600}})
```

takes over two minutes. There has to be a better way!

Comment: Could you please include the output of `db.coll.find(...).explain()`?

Answer (score 4):

This was pretty fun - thanks for the question.

**Note**: this answer only finds documents whose period intersects the evaluation interval (the bottom part of your question). This would be a step in an aggregation pipeline that accomplishes the top part of your question - which is a pretty big question. You would have to have a much more complete question for that to be answered adequately.

I noticed that your query logic didn't completely match your description so I tried to guess at what you are trying to do and build a test case.

You should be able to open a mongo shell, `use timeSeries` and then paste this in to verify the concepts. The last couple of lines show how to debug your 70,000,000 document case - both for index coverage and execution time.

NOTE: [mongo-hacker](https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker) makes examining this kind of output much easier.

```
// USE:
//   mongo timeSeries < thisFile

// Clean out previous runs during testing
db.timeSeries1.drop()

// Given a start/finish 30 sec interval, find all documents that were
// active at that time.

// timeSeries1 holds period in epoch seconds the session was active
// Index start and finish independently - our queries use them independently
db.timeSeries1.ensureIndex({start:1})
db.timeSeries1.ensureIndex({finish:1})

// ASSUME: intervals do not overlap [0,29] and [30,59]
var intervalStart = 13653506600;
var intervalFinish = 13653506629;

// Use cases - should find all 5
//  1. active session matches interval exactly
db.timeSeries1.insert({_id:1, start:intervalStart, finish:intervalFinish})
//  2. active session starts and ends within interval
db.timeSeries1.insert({_id:2, start:intervalStart+5, finish:intervalFinish-5})
//  3. active session starts before interval and ends during interval
db.timeSeries1.insert({_id:3, start:intervalStart-5, finish:intervalFinish-5})
//  4. active session starts during interval and ends after interval
db.timeSeries1.insert({_id:4, start:intervalStart+5, finish:intervalFinish+5})
//  5. active session starts before interval and ends after interval
db.timeSeries1.insert({_id:5, start:intervalStart-5, finish:intervalFinish+5})

// Query should return docs if:
//  the interval is within the active session
//  the active session begins or ends within the interval
//    the active session is within the interval - special 'and' case of above
//
var query = {
  $or: [
    {start: {$gte: intervalStart, $lte: intervalFinish}},
    {finish: {$gte: intervalStart, $lte: intervalFinish}},
    {$and: [
      {start: {$lt: intervalStart}},
      {finish: {$gt: intervalFinish}}
    ]}
  ]
}

// Verify all 5 use cases found
db.timeSeries1.find(query)

// Verify index coverage - each stage is an IXSCAN
db.timeSeries1.explain().find(query)

// Verify that executionStats nReturned is not much more than
// totalKeysExamined.
// Examine execution times
db.timeSeries1.explain("executionStats").find(query)
```